# Multiple inheritance of User Class (with FOSUseBundle)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, multiple-inheritance

In a Symfony2 project, I have a User class, which inherits from the FOSUserBundle. This User class has a few basic attributes (first and last name, email, phone, etc.), and represents all the users that can connect to the application.

What I would like to do now is to implement a new class called "Person" (which represents an independent person, external to the app), that has very similar attributes to the User class.

Actually, a User is a Person, however a Person is not a User. Logically, the User class should inherit from the Person class.

Nevertheless, my User class already inherits from the BaseUser class (which, I understood, is necessary in order to use FOSUserBundle ; am I wrong ?), therefore, inheriting the User class from the Person class will not be possible, as multiple inheritance is not available in PHP.

Then, how could I implement this Person class ? I can't find any other solution, and I guess inheriting the BaseUser class from a custom class is not a good practice (if it is even possible). I discovered skimming through the PHP docs the "traits", but I didn't really understood the concept, and if it could be helpful (and if so, then how). I didn't find any similar problem on any forum. Is there any workaround or solution to this case(I precise I'd like to keep FOSUB) ?

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: Could you please clarify why `a User is a Person, however a Person is not a User`? Perhaps you don't need such inheritance here at all.

Comment: I mean that the User has all the characteristics of the Person, but the User has few more characteristics (like the last login datetime, etc.). I rather meant `a User is a Person, however a Person is not necessarily a User`.

Comment: You may find a multi-user bundle such as [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) useful.  It allows for more than one class of person.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this bundle. However, as a Person is external and independent to the application (therefore Persons cannot login to the app), I'm not sure it perfectly fits my needs.